# PHP+HTML с использованием конструкции match

Tags: php

Сделал комбо режим PHP+HTML, но опять ошибка.
Как пофиксить этот баг?

```html
<?php 
$a = 2;
?>

<?php match($a){?>

<?php 1 => ?> <div class ="">вода</div> <?php , ?>

<?php 2 => ?> <div class ="">свет</div> <?php , ?>

<?php default => ?> <div class ="">ничего не найдено</div> <?php , ?>

<?php }; ?>
```

Comment: Потому что вот это `<?php , ?>`  как минимум ошибка синтаксиса

Comment: Ребята, конечно, отвечают на твои вопросы, но в реальной разработке никто не будет писать такой код. А если и будет - то ему настучат по рукам. Так что по сути это пустая трата времени.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a = 2;
$returnValue = match ($a) {
    1 => '<div class ="">вода</div>',
    2 => '<div class ="">свет</div>',
    default => '<div class ="">ничего не найдено</div>',
};

echo $returnValue;
```

Comment: А почему здесь не будет работать html, если обернуть их в  двойные кавычки " " С чем это связано?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php

Comment: Прочитал статью, но так и не понял. Сказано, что в отличие от синтаксиса двойных кавычек и heredoc, переменные и управляющие последовательности для специальных символов, заключённых в одинарные кавычки, не обрабатываются.

Comment: строки заключаются в одинарные или двойные кавычки...... что произойдёт когда строка, заключённая в двойные кавычки внутри будет иметь ещё одни? визуально на листочке или в блокноте введите данные, посмотрите. Что увидите?

Comment: разве <div class ="">вода</div> имеет внутри еще кавычки? class="" тоже считается за кавычки?

Comment: Конечно, а почему они не должны считаться за кавычки?

Comment: Это не баг. Но синтаксическая ошибка возникать будет, если писать не по правилам (а данном случае писать двойные кавычки в двойных) .............нет никакой "глубокой вложенности". Есть правила как можно что писать. В той ссылке кстати всё написано....просто надо читать до самого низа..

Comment: Значит у одинарных кавычек более глубокая вложенность, чем у двойных? Чем и помогает нам избежать этого казуса с class ="" ?

Comment: Что такое " писать ен? "

Comment: *не  ............

Comment: Все ясно. Хороший вы человек =)

Answer (score 0):

Можете сделать что-то типа:

```
<?= match ($a) {
    1 => '<div class ="">вода</div>',
    2 => '<div> class ="">свет</div>',
    default => '<div class ="">ничего не найдено</div>',
};
?>
```